# Parsing of 24hr date format doesn't work as expected when time is in 12th hr(12-1 PM)

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am using below code to parse text to date datatype and get respective long value.

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String TIMEZONE_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(TIMEZONE_DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = df.parse("2015-09-21T12:48:00+0000");
date.getTime();
```

In the above case I get `getTime()` value as: `1442796480000` which is `12:48 AM(GMT)`. But I am expecting `12:48 PM` as its 24 hr format.

When I use the same code with text date: `2015-09-21T13:48:00+0000`, I get 1:48 PM which is correct.

Am I using the wrong date format?

Comment: in 24 hr format, 00:48 should be 12:48 AM and 12:48 should be 12:48 PM right? that is what I am thinking

Comment: Get rid of java.Date. It's lucifer reincarnated in a java class

Comment: Got an answer from Egeo, HH instead of hh. Which works for me. That's still weird that 13:48 doesn't throw an error as an invalid date String if `hh` is used.

Comment: By default, date parsing is lenient. Which means it tries anyway (and may give unintended results). From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)): *"By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false)."*

Comment: Like @aran I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 24h the pattern should be HH instead hh

Comment: thanks, this works :)
But weird that 13:48 doesn't throw an error as an invalid date String if `hh` is used.

Comment: @BikasKatwal I agree, `SimpleDateFormat` is weird. I wouldn’t want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 8);
System.out.println(date);
SimpleDateFormat simpDate;
simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
System.out.println(simpDate.format(date));
```

It worked fine for me! :)

Comment: Just to be clear, `kk` is not zero based. It goes from 1 to 24, which may not be exactly what you want.